# Insert a char* at the beginning of another char* C++

Tags: c++, string, pointers, char

I was wondering if there´s any way at all of inserting a `char*` at the beginning of another `char*`.

For example:

```
char* a;
char* b;
char* ba;

a="HOW ARE YOU?";
b="HELLO, ";
```

I want to insert in ab first, `char* b`, and after that, `char* a`, so the content of `char* ba` would be

`"HELLO, HOW ARE YOU?"`

Is that possible?

Thank you veery much

Comment: You can't modify string constants. Use `std::string`, it makes this very easy.

Comment: Err, the thing is I cannot use strings in this specific problem. 
Do you know why is people voting negative on my question?

Comment: At least part of the problem appears to be that you don't understand the difference between a C string (not a `std::string`) and a pointer to character.

Comment: I expect it's because you're asking how to do something that you should never do, and you didn't mention that you couldn't use the obvious solution.

Answer (score 9):

As @alan already mentioned, use [`std::string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string)

```
std::string a = "How are you?", b = "Hello, ", ba;
ba = b + a;
```

*Update:*

As @Vlad correctly pointed out, it is not necessary to use `std::string` for the string constants. You can use `const char*` instead. But now, you cannot say

```
ba = b + a;
```

anymore, because this would add char pointers, which is not possible.

You must split the concatenation into two operations instead

```
const char *a = "How are you?";
const char *b = "Hello, ";
std::string ba;
ba = b;
ba += a;
```

If you really, really must use plain C strings (as in, this is my homework or my boss threatens to fire me otherwise), you can use @Vlad's approach, of course. But you should wrap it in a function, which takes care of the calculation and allocation.

*But*, you must still be aware of the memory issue. You are now responsible for freeing the allocated memory.

Comment: It is a stupid solution. There is no any need to define two objects of type std::string because underlaying string literals will not be changed. So instead of writing this stupid code std::string a = "How are you?", b = "Hello, "; it would be enough to write const char *a = "How are you?", *b = "Hello, ";

Comment: You are right in that it is not *necessary*. But OP obviously is neither an expert in [tag:c] nor in [tag:c++]. So, I've taken the liberty to push him in the direction of the "C++ way" of doing strings. As soon as he masters the low level parts of *C* strings and memory management, he will learn himself how to do it correctly. But until then, I take your comment as an insult and as dangerous as well.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow: At least one will have to be converted to `string` anyway to concatenate, so unless you really need to micro-optimise there's little point mucking around with C-style pointers. I certainly don't see how it's "stupid" to use `string` to represent a string.

Comment: @ Mike Seymour I do not think that there is any need to refer to std:;string because this changes the sense of the original post. I consider the original post such a way that there are already defined two pointers and there is a need to define a third pointer that will point to the concatenated string literals.

Answer (score 6):

There is no problem if ba points to a dynamically allocated array or is itself an array that can accomodate these two string literals. For example

```
char *ba = new char[ std::strlen( a ) + std::strlen( b ) + 1];

std::strcpy( ba, b );
std::strcat( ba, a );
```

Comment: This code works but it’s genuinely horrible C++. Don’t write that.

Comment: @khajvah Because it needs encapsulating to make it safe and easy to use, and then you've just reinvented `std::string`.

Comment: There is nothing horrible as Konrad Rudolph are trying to frighten you. It is safe enough.

Comment: @Vlad No, it’s every bit as horrible as I’ve said. In fact, I would reject such code in a code review. I would (and have, in the past!) deduct points if a student handed this in as an assignment, and as a matter of principle I will not answer questions of Stack Overflow if the OP uses manual memory management: they are welcome to make their lives hard for themselves, but I will not help them with that. And while I wouldn’t downvote this answer (it’s technically correct), I am baffled at the number of upvotes it’s got – It doesn’t deserve them.

Comment: Yes, skip all the important safety and correctness parts, that'll make a great answer.

Comment: I can not even consider your comment seriously. First of all it is not clear whether the code is written in C or in C++. Moreover I think that the original code is written in C because pointers to string literals have no qualifier const. Secondly it is obvious that it is an assignment on theme about pointers. Thirdly it is also obvious that smart pointers are not known to the author. There is no any need to use for example std:;string for such simple operation because the first two pointers are pointers to string literals. So your long comment may be simply ignotrd by the author.

Comment: Moreover the solution suggested by @Olaf Dietsche is stupid. There is no any need to define two objects of type std::string instead of using pointers to string literals that will be changed never.

Comment: @Vlad The question *says* that it’s using C++. And if smart pointers are not known to the author (fine) then using raw pointers sounds like an even worse idea. It’s not at all clear that this is an assignment. Using strings here is simply less error-prone than using raw pointers and hence the preferred solution in production code. Olaf’s solution is far from stupid. Of course you don’t need strings for literals, but as soon as you concatenate these former literals, you do need to convert them.

Comment: And “such a simple operation”, as you call it, is causing millions of software bugs the world over. It’s irresponsible not to avoid this source of bugs entirely, which is trivially possible in C++. Teaching bad code is likewise irresponsible. We don’t need more crappy code, we need *better* code. And hence programmers that learn, from day 1, to write clean code.

Comment: @Konrad Rudolph Any code can be written including bugs even when you use std::string. I do not see any wrong in writing const char *a = "HOW ARE YOU?"; instead of std::string a = "HOW ARE YOU?"; Moreover the last statement can be the reason of a run-time error if there is no enough memory in the heap.

Comment: “Any code can be written including bugs” – Of course. But you can excluded *specific classes* of bugs by following some patterns. | “I do not see any wrong in writing const char *a = "HOW ARE YOU?"; instead of std::string a = "HOW ARE YOU?";” – There’s nothing wrong with that. But nobody is talking about this piece of code. We’re talking about manual memory management.

Answer (score -1):

You could use:

```
char * strcpy ( char * destination, const char * source );

/* strcpy example */
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main ()
{
  char str1[]="Sample string";
  char str2[40];
  char str3[40];
  strcpy (str2,str1);
  strcpy (str3,"copy successful");
  printf ("str1: %s\nstr2: %s\nstr3: %s\n",str1,str2,str3);
  return 0;
}
```